# Что может значить фраза "звукопроникающая способность шифера"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Однажды один мой знакомый сказал:

> звукопроникающая способность шифера.

Это не дает мне покоя. Что это вообще значит?

**Обновлено**

*Дело не столько в том, что он имел в виду. Это понятно.
Вопрос в том, что он сказал на самом деле.
Проникающая способность излучений.
Способность излучения проникать.
Проникающая способность шифера.
Способность шифера проникать.
Способность чья? Шифера.
Значит, у шифера есть способность - звукопроникновение* ‍♀️ *(что бы это ни значило).
Видимо, это способность шифера проникать в звук.*

*Куда и кто проникает?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Звукопроникающая способность шифера***?

**Фраза некорректна.** В этом случае используются такие термины для характеристики материала: **звукопроницаемость, звуконепроницаемость**. Также можно сказать: **звукопоглощающая** способность шифера.

Ошибка связана со следующими фразами: шифер проницаем/непроницаем для звука, звук проникает сквозь шифер.

Тогда исходная фраза могла бы звучать так: ***шиферопроникающая способность звука***. Но так не принято говорить.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл-то понятен: речь о том, насколько хорошо шифер поглощает звуки. Но сформулировано кривовато.

Comment: Проникающая способность излучений. Способность излучения проникать.
Проникающая способность шифера. Способность шифера проникать. Способность, чья? Шифера.
Значит шифер куда то проникает. Видимо это способность шифера проникать в звук.